# Push to Heroku error: contextify@0.1.14 install

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am a new node.js developer.
I'm trying to push my node.js app to Heroku but I keep getting some error as follow, but no idea how to go about fixing it.

```
-----> Building dependencies
   Pruning any extraneous modules
   Installing node modules (package.json)

   > contextify@0.1.14 install /tmp/build_7fb89e69944f674de0fcbcbe650a0b7b/lucinkudumov-galdraland-dfa13e5/node_modules/email-templates/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
   > node-gyp rebuild

   (node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
   make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_7fb89e69944f674de0fcbcbe650a0b7b/lucinkudumov-galdraland-dfa13e5/node_modules/email-templates/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build'
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
   In file included from ../src/contextify.cc:3:0:
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
   NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
   ^
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
   NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
   ^
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
   , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
   ^
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
   , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
   ^
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
   v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
   ^
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
   v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
   ^
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: error: call of overloaded ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’ is ambiguous
   return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
   ^
   ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
   In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:25:0,
   from ../src/contextify.cc:3:
   /app/.node-gyp/4.1.2/src/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
   NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/4.1.2/src/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’
   /app/.node-gyp/4.1.2/src/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
```

...

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem.
Contextify is not supported in node 4.x.
So I've downgrade node to 0.10.x, then works fine.

Sorry my noise.

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts are to review the `package.json` file and check for errors.  Also check the [versions of each npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/) you are including in `package.json` and ensure they are the latest versions.

Also [define the latest version of node](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version) in `package.json`.

Javascript / node libraries can update regularly and if you are following a tutorial you may need to update some package versions